# Submit em form BootStrap não passa dados via post!

Tags: php, html

Olá, 
Estou com um formulário html usando bootstrap, porém não consigo enviar via post.
*detalhe, form sem usar style bootstrap vai sem problemas.
segue meu form:

```
<div class="row contact-wrap"> 
                <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
                <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>NOME *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>EMAIL *</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>TELEFONE *</label>
                            <input type="number" name="telephone" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>NOME DA EMPRESA</label>
                            <input type="text" name="employer" class="form-control">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>ASSUNTO *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>SUA MENSAGEM *</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" required="required" value="ENVIAR">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
```

Comment: vc faz isso direto ou usa algum javascript? o `$_POST` vem em branco no php? deu um `print_r()`?

Comment: @Fabricio , poderia colocar mais detalhes do arquivo sendemail.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta so ir no seu php e faz isto:

```
<?php
   $nome = $_POST['name'];
   print_r($nome);
?>
```

Foi como referiram ai no comentário mas testa só.
Lembrando que no php quando faz um submit no form, tu tem de utilizar o name do field e não o ID.

Comment: Sai nada!
Mas se eu fizer o submit com o form fora do estilo bootstrap, vai sem problemas. Não quero usar js para fazer só essa parte.

Comment: nem precisa, nao percebi ainda qual é o problema? Se quer so receber os dados do form, desta maneira irá funcionar :)

Comment: method="post" action="sendemail.php", e o name dos fields vai ser o que tu tem de pegar na area de php. Isso irá funcionar sem problema algum